# Producing all possible permutations from a dict + list

Tags: python, python-itertools

I need to generate a list of dicts that show all possible permutations of two values. (I’m testing UI components so I need to see how they render in all possible circumstances, however unlikely.) I can do it with a list comprehension:

```py
values = [True, False]
variants = ({
    'Field X': x,
    'Field Y': y,
    'Field Z': z,
} for x in values for y in values for z in values)
```

to produce:

```py
>>> list(variants)
[{'Field X': True, 'Field Y': True, 'Field Z': True}, {'Field X': True, 'Field Y': True, 'Field Z': False}, {'Field X': True, 'Field Y': False, 'Field Z': True}, {'Field X': True, 'Field Y': False, 'Field Z': False}, {'Field X': False, 'Field Y': True, 'Field Z': True}, {'Field X': False, 'Field Y': True, 'Field Z': False}, {'Field X': False, 'Field Y': False, 'Field Z': True}, {'Field X': False, 'Field Y': False, 'Field Z': False}]
```

This is OK as far as it goes when I have (as here) three fields and two values, but it gets hairy when I have dozens of fields with multiple values! I reckon there must be an easy way to do this with `itertools` but don’t know what that is. Something with `itertools.product()` maybe?

Answer (score 2):

Use `itertools.product(values, repeat=3)` to get every combination of 3 values.

```
variants = [{
    'Field X': x,
    'Field Y': y,
    'Field Z': z,
} for x in values for y in values for z in itertools.product(values, repeat=3)]
```

If you have a dynamic list of fields, you can create the dictionary dynamically using `dict(zip(...))`

```
values=[True, False]
fields=['Field X', 'Field Y', 'Field Z']
variants = [
    dict(zip(fields, values))
    for values in itertools.product(values, repeat=len(fields))
]
```